# Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition]

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openfeign

Im using feign client to make rest calls between microservices, When i execute it using IntelliJ IDEA its working fine. But if i execute it with jar it gives me following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.loadbalancer.EurekaLoadBalancerClientConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:155)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:108)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstances(NamedContextFactory.java:203)
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.lambda$execute$2(RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:118)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:113)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.fundTransfer(Unknown Source)
        at com.core.banking.user.service.internetbanking.acl.service.FundTransferService.fundTransfer(FundTransferService.java:19)
        at com.core.banking.user.service.internetbanking.acl.event.EventHandler.lambda$onEvent$0(EventHandler.java:38)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.getCondition(ConditionEvaluator.java:124)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:96)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

POM File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.core.banking.user.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>internet-banking-acl-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>internet-banking-acl-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: We currently experience the same thing and are trying to resolve it..

Answer (score 4):

We had the same issue. After a research we found out that the issue is similar to described [in the feign client bug.](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/475)

The temporary fix provided by [DenisKorolev](https://github.com/DenisKorolev) resolves the issue by setting correct ClassLoader during context initialisation.

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory(LoadBalancerClientsProperties properties) {
        return new LoadBalancerClientFactory(properties) {
            @Override
            protected AnnotationConfigApplicationContext createContext(String name) {
                // FIXME: temporary switch classloader to use the correct one when creating the context
                ClassLoader originalClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = super.createContext(name);
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalClassLoader);
                return context;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed at new Spring Cloud version (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/pull/1256). So I updated Spring Cloud to 2022.0.4 in my pom.xml. It works for me.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```